# what is the equivalent data type for geo_point in hibernate search?

Tags: elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I am using elastic search with hibernate search.I want to make one property data type as geo_point ,so that I can draw tile map using kibana.Is there any equivalent data type in hibernate search for geo_point in elastic search?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spatial feature of Hibernate Search:

```
import org.hibernate.search.annotations.*;

@Entity
@Indexed
@Spatial
public class Hotel {

  @Latitude
  Double latitude

  @Longitude
  Double longitude

  // ...
}
```

You will end up with a `geo_point` field named `location` in your document.

For more information: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#spatial

Comment: Hi Yoann, I am using spatial annotation but getting below exception. org.hibernate.search.engine.metadata.impl.TypeMetadata$Builder.getAnalyzerReference(TypeMetadata.java:631).Any suggestion?

Comment: Answered to the dedicated question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818907/how-to-use-spatial-annotation/45822540#45822540